# Parsing dota2.gamepedia.com - Android

Tags: android, parsing, wiki

I would like to get all information about Dota2 items I can get. Essential ones are their prices, names, thumbnail picture URLs, but other information are also welcome, like the way you buy them (for instance, you buy a `Moon Shard` by buying two `Hyperstone`s).

There is a [Dota2 Wiki page](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Items) and there is a [way](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Android_%28operating_system%29&prop=sections) to parse Wiki pages, but this didn't work. Apparently Wiki's APIs doesn't work on http://dota2.gamepedia.com.

I need this information on Android platform.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually been actively researching this same thing.

Scraping from a wiki is far too brittle (layout/website updates), why not get the data straight from valve's mouth? They have an online [item viewer](https://www.dota2.com/items/) which consumes json item data, I was able to track down where exactly this gets published and plan on using it in a future android app as well.

The json data can be retreived via [this link](http://www.dota2.com/jsfeed/heropediadata?feeds=itemdata&v=3206368Q9QYH2VRrw8j&l=english).

Once you have that look into something like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to parse this data directly into objects.

Personally however, I would consume it through some other method and store it in your own database so your app isn't dictated by the structure of the data they push.

Hope this helps!